# Get statuses of network printers

Tags: linux, network-printer

we are tasked with finding exactly how many pages were printed by all IP printers on a fairly large network, and then doing a lot of things with that data. There are about 15 different printer manufacturers, all of which have different http gui, however nearly all of them support IPP. Is it possible to find how many pages were printed by a specific printer in the last month, or number of total pages printed by using IPP, or other standardized protocol?

Service will be running on RedHat.

Update:
SNMP gives all the information that we need, however only a few Printers support it(Some of the printers that we have might even be old enough to go straight to a museum in a couple years). So, IPP is only thing that I have available that's guaranteed to be supported by all machines.

Comment: Possibly using SNMP, if all of the printers support it.

Comment: Can I ask if you got a printserver & if it's a Windows's server ? I see the service will run on linux, but I was wondering for the printserver. As I know papercut software or such tool rely on the eventlog to make the 'credit'/pagecount per user.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no print-server. Clients connect to printers directly and print/copy/scan anything they want as much as they want.

Comment: IMO the best way to do it is via a print server (as mentioned above by yagmoth555). Othervvise you will have a lot of balagan.